# Is there any way to replace a missing value based on another columns' value to match the column name

Tags: r, replace, missing-data

I have a dataset:

```
    a day day.1.time day.2.time day.3.time day.4.time day.5.time
1  NA   2          4          5          7         10          4
2  NA   5          4          1          1          6         NA
3  NA   3          7          9          6          7          4
4  NA   3          6          8          8          4          5
5  NA   3          5          2          4          5          6
6  NA   3         87          3          2          1         78
7  NA   1         NA          7          5          9         54
8  NA   5          6          6          3          2          3
9  NA   2          5         10          9          8          3
10 NA   3          9          4         10          3          3
```

I am trying to use the `day` column value to match with the `day.x.time` column to replace the missing value in column `a`. For instance, in the first row, the first value in the `day` column is 2, then we should use `day.2.time` value 5 to replace the first value in column `a`.

If the `day.x.time` value is missing, we should use -1 day or +1 day to replace the missing in column `a`. For instance, in the second row, the `day` column shows 5, so we should use the value in `day.5.time` column, but it's also a missing value. In this case, we should use the value in `day.4.time` column to replace the missing value in column `a`.

You can use `dat = data.frame(a = rep(NA,10), day = c(2,5,3,3,3,3,1,5,2,3), day.1.time = c(4,4,7,6,5,87,NA,6,5,9), day.2.time = sample(10), day.3.time = sample(10), day.4.time = sample(10), day.5.time = c(4,NA,4,5,6,78,54,3,3,3))` to generate the sample data.

I have tried `grep(paste0("^day."dat$day,".time$", names(dat))` to match with the column but my code isn't matching in every row, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: and what if -1 and +1 day is also `NA` do you want to go for -2 and +2 day or just return `NA`  ?

Comment: @RonakShah great question. Maybe try -2 and +2 days and then return NA. My original dataset has 30 days so I guess there might be some chances to still return NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this.

The first part is easy to match `day` column with the corresponding `day.x.time` column.  We can do this using matrix subsetting.

```
cols <- grep('day\\.\\d+\\.time', names(dat))
dat$a <- dat[cols][cbind(1:nrow(dat), dat$day)]
dat
#    a day day.1.time day.2.time day.3.time day.4.time day.5.time
#1   3   2          4          3          3          3          4
#2  NA   5          4          4         10          2         NA
#3   1   3          7          8          1          8          4
#4   4   3          6          6          4          5          5
#5   6   3          5         10          6          7          6
#6   8   3         87          5          8          9         78
#7  NA   1         NA          1          7         10         54
#8   3   5          6          7          9          1          3
#9   2   2          5          2          5          6          3
#10  2   3          9          9          2          4          3
```

To fill values where `day.x.time` column is `NA` we can select the closest non-NA value in that row.

```
inds <- which(is.na(dat$a))
dat$a[inds] <- mapply(function(x, y) 
         na.omit(unlist(dat[x, cols[order(abs(y- seq_along(cols)))]])[1:4])[1],
              inds, dat$day[inds])

dat
#   a day day.1.time day.2.time day.3.time day.4.time day.5.time
#1  3   2          4          3          3          3          4
#2  2   5          4          4         10          2         NA
#3  1   3          7          8          1          8          4
#4  4   3          6          6          4          5          5
#5  6   3          5         10          6          7          6
#6  8   3         87          5          8          9         78
#7  1   1         NA          1          7         10         54
#8  3   5          6          7          9          1          3
#9  2   2          5          2          5          6          3
#10 2   3          9          9          2          4          3
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Would that possible to limit the replacing value in the range of -2, +2 days?

Comment: @Y.Z. I guess the updated answer should work for -2, +2 days range.

Comment: Thanks again. That's what I am looking for. just one tiny edit, I changed the column order from `1:4` to `c(2,3,1,4)` instead.

Comment: @Y.Z. Do you mean columns `day.1.time` `day2.time` etc are not in order? You can use `gtools::mixedsort` to sort the columns if you need.

Comment: I mean the replacing column order. Right now, our replacing order is -2 day, -1 day, +1 day and +2 day. I changed the replacing order to -1 day, +1 day, -2 day and +2 day.

Comment: Not really, right now it will go to -1 day first then +1 day, -2 day then +2 day.

Comment: My bad. I just read your code again, just find out that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sapply` to loop over the rows and subset by `day[i] + 2` column.

```
res <- transform(dat, a=sapply(1:nrow(dat), function(i) dat[i, dat$day[i] + 2]))
res
#     a day day.1.time day.2.time day.3.time day.4.time day.5.time
# 1   5   2          4          5          7         10          4
# 2  NA   5          4          1          1          6         NA
# 3   6   3          7          9          6          7          4
# 4   8   3          6          8          8          4          5
# 5   4   3          5          2          4          5          6
# 6   2   3         87          3          2          1         78
# 7  NA   1         NA          7          5          9         54
# 8   3   5          6          6          3          2          3
# 9  10   2          5         10          9          8          3
# 10 10   3          9          4         10          3          3
```

### Edit

The +/-2 days would require a decision rule, what to chose, if `day` is `NA`, but none of `day - 1` and `day + 1` is `NA` and both have the same values.

Here a solution that goes from `day` backwards and takes the first non-`NA`. If it is day one, as it's the case in row `7`, we get `NA`.

```
res <- transform(dat, a=sapply(1:nrow(dat), function(i) {
  days <- dat[i, -(1:2)]
  day.value <- days[dat$day[i]]
  if (is.na(day.value)) {
    day.value <- tail(na.omit(unlist(days[1:dat$day[i]])), 1)
    if (length(day.value) == 0) day.value <- NA
  }
  return(day.value)
}))
res
#     a day day.1.time day.2.time day.3.time day.4.time day.5.time
# 1  10   2          4         10          1          2          4
# 2  10   5          4          1          3         10         NA
# 3   2   3          7          7          2          7          4
# 4   6   3          6          2          6          6          5
# 5  10   3          5          9         10          5          6
# 6   8   3         87          6          8          4         78
# 7  NA   1         NA          3          7          1         54
# 8   3   5          6          4          4          9          3
# 9   8   2          5          8          5          8          3
# 10  9   3          9          5          9          3          3
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I know I could apply the same code again to get -1 and -2 days but would that possible to consider both -2 , -1, same day, +1, +2 days in the same code?